# Geo-tagging in Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I am working on an Application that requires the user to be able to geo-tag picture taken via the camera. The application is to encourage user geo-tag trees to encourage afforestation and reduce global warming.

Is it possible to implement this feature and how can I implement it?

NB: This is my first major project.

Comment: Do not understand the problem. Camera apps on Android devices will put the location in the Exif header. What do you want more?

Comment: I mean, a situation where you take a picture and the camera grabs the location where the picture was taken.

Comment: Yes. And puts it in the picture. Then you are done. What do you want else?

Comment: Oh now I get you. Is it possible to get closer location details like co-ordinate

Comment: Sorry i do not understand that question(without questionmark yet)

Comment: Oh now I get you. Is it possible to get closer location details like co-ordinate?

Answer (score 0):

Creating a comfortable user experience with location is a big task. These are some of the concerns you'll have to address:

1. The user may have disabled location globally.
2. The app may not have the permission to use location.
3. You want to ask the user for permission and/or to enable location.
4. You don't want to bother the user by asking over and over again.
5. Asking for permission means pausing your activity in favor of a system activity that asks for permission. There's a similar but distinct mechanism to ask to enable the location.
6. Your activity will resume when the user responds, you need to override a special callback method that receives the result.
7. It's not good to try to fetch location just when you need it. It may take time. Instead you have to ask Android at the outset to push location updates to you.
8. The user may revoke the location permission while using the app, you must constantly re-check the permissions, be resilient to sudden exceptions, and repeat the request to receive location updates when the location permission comes back.

Here are some snippets from my project that can help you get started:

```
private val Context.fusedLocationProviderClient get() = getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)

private suspend fun FusedLocationProviderClient.tryFetchLastLocation(): Location? =
    lastLocation.await()
        ?.also { info { "Got response from getLastLocation()" } }
        ?: run { warn { "getLastLocation() returned null" }; null }

suspend fun Context.canUseLocationFg() =
        appHasLocationPermission() && 
        locationSettingsException(locationRequestFg, locationRequestBg) == null
```

```
import android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
import androidx.core.content.PermissionChecker.PERMISSION_GRANTED

fun Context.appHasLocationPermission() =
        checkSelfPermission(this, ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PERMISSION_GRANTED

suspend fun Context.locationSettingsException(
        vararg locationRequests: LocationRequest
): ApiException? = try {
    getSettingsClient(this)
            .checkLocationSettings(LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
                    .addAllLocationRequests(locationRequests.asList()).build())
            .await()
    null
} catch (e: ApiException) { e }
```

```
const val CODE_REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION = 13
const val CODE_RESOLVE_API_EXCEPTION = 14

suspend fun Fragment.checkAndCorrectPermissionsAndSettings() {
    with(context!!) {
        if (!appHasLocationPermission()) {
            warn { "FG: our app has no permission to access fine location" }
            delay(WAIT_MILLISECONDS_BEFORE_ASKING)
            if (!appHasLocationPermission()) {
                startIntentRequestLocationPermission()
                return
            }
        }
        if (locationSettingsException(locationRequestFg, locationRequestBg) == null) return
        warn { "FG: ResolvableApiException for location request (probably location disabled)" }
        if (!mainPrefs.shouldAskToEnableLocation) return
        delay(WAIT_MILLISECONDS_BEFORE_ASKING)
        locationSettingsException(locationRequestFg, locationRequestBg)
                ?.let { it as? ResolvableApiException }
                ?.also { startIntentResolveException(it) }
    }
}

fun Fragment.startIntentRequestLocationPermission() =
        requestPermissions(arrayOf(ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION), CODE_REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION)

fun Fragment.startIntentResolveException(e: ResolvableApiException) =
        startIntentSenderForResult(e.resolution.intentSender, CODE_RESOLVE_API_EXCEPTION, null, 0, 0, 0, null)
```

```
override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
    if (requestCode != CODE_REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION) return
    permissions.zip(grantResults.asList())
        .find { (perm, _) -> perm == ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION }
        ?.also { (_, result) ->
            if (result == PermissionChecker.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                info { "User has granted us the fine location permission" }
            } else {
                warn { "User hasn't granted us the fine location permission (grant result: ${grantResults[0]})" }
            }
        }
}

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    if (requestCode != CODE_RESOLVE_API_EXCEPTION) return
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        info { "ResolvableApiException is now resolved" }
    } else {
        warn { "ResolvableApiException resolution failed with code $resultCode" }
        activity!!.mainPrefs.applyUpdate { setShouldAskToEnableLocation(false) }
    }
}
```

```
val locationRequestFg = LocationRequest().apply {
    interval = 1000
    fastestInterval = 10
    priority = PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY
}

suspend fun Context.receiveLocationUpdatesFg(locationState: LocationState) {
    fusedLocationProviderClient.apply {
        tryFetchLastLocation()?.also {
            info { "lastLocation: ${it.description}" }
            locationState.location = it
        }
        LocationCallbackFg.locationState = locationState
        requestLocationUpdates(locationRequestFg, LocationCallbackFg, null).await()
        info(CC_PRIVATE) { "FG: started receiving location updates" }
    }
}

object LocationCallbackFg : LocationCallback() {
    var locationState: LocationState? = null

    override fun onLocationResult(result: LocationResult) {
        val lastLocation = result.lastLocation
        info { "FG: received location ${lastLocation.description}" }
        locationState?.apply { location = lastLocation }
                ?: warn { "LocationCallbackFg received an event while not in use" }
    }
}
```

The code relies on `Task.await()`, this is in Kotlin's library `kotlinx-coroutines-play-services`.